# How upload blob in Azure Blob Storage with specified ContentType with .NET v12 SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I just started the Quickstart with .NET v12 SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet

But i cant seem to find out how to specify a ContentType when uploading a blob.

Does anyone know that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set it as follows,

```
 await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true, default);
 await blobClient.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders
 {
    ContentType = contentType
 });
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned in the comment, the efficient way to do the same with a single method as follows,

```
await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, new BlobHttpHeaders{ ContentType = "text/plain"});
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Sajeetharan! I also just found out that you can upload the blob and specify ContentType with one single call "await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, new BlobHttpHeaders{ ContentType = "text/plain" });"

Answer (score 6):

Please try this override of [`UploadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClient_UploadAsync_System_IO_Stream_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobHttpHeaders_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_IProgress_System_Int64__System_Nullable_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_AccessTier__Azure_Storage_StorageTransferOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method. This method will upload and set the content type in a single network call.

Here would be your code:

```
var httpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
 {
    ContentType = contentType
 });
await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, httpHeaders);
```

Comment: With this override of UploadAsync, it's also possible to set the metadata for the blob.

Comment: @AmélieDupré - Overload takes an instance of `BlobUploadOptions`, which facilitates Metadata.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobuploadoptions?view=azure-dotnet