# Converting IFormFile to Stream set content type to application/octet-stream

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload image files to a Azure Blob Container. I am using .net core webapi post method to upload the image.The upload getting success but the content type is invalid, which convert the original `image/jpeg` type to `application/octet-stream`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Post(IFormFile files)
{
    BlobClient blobClient = _containerClient.GetBlobClient(files.FileName);
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(files.OpenReadStream());
}
```

Can anyone help me how to upload the image keeping the original content type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember seeing a question some time ago which talked about getting content type of a file using file name (and extension) in asp.net core (not able to find it now, sorry). Please look at that. Once you have that, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945376/how-upload-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-with-specified-contenttype-with-net-v12-s.

Comment: Actually found a separate link for mime type: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/08/14/getting-a-mime-type-from-a-file-name-in-net-core/. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri I can get the original mime type by using IFormFile. But here the issue is when i upload it to azure blob storage, there it show as `application/octet-stream`

Comment: In that case check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945376/how-upload-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-with-specified-contenttype-with-net-v12-s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set content-type when you upload file to Azure blob, please refer to the following code

```
// I use the sdk Azure.Storage.Blobs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Post(IFormFile file)
{
    var connectionString = "the account connection string";
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient =blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            BlobHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders() { 
               ContentType=file.ContentType 
            };

            await blobClient.UploadAsync(file.OpenReadStream(), httpHeaders);

            return "OK";
}
```

Test(I test in Postman)
[image]
[image]