# How to upload image in blob storage using ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to upload an image as I also create a new row in mysql database. The instruction given to me is that images should be stored in Azure blob storage while info are stored in mysql database.

This is my code for creating a new row

```
// POST: Books/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
// more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult>Create([Bind("Id,Isbn,Price,Rank,Title,Genre,Author,Overview,Summary,Publisher,PubDate,Pages,Length,Width,Height,Weight")] Books books)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var responseTask = Client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Books", books);
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return View(books);
}
```

Now I don't have any idea what codes to put in so I can upload an image alongside it

Please help me I need to pass this project in 24hrs and I am still far from the projected outcome

Answer (score 0):

So, at first, you need to add a new property which type is `IFormFile` into your   `Books` model, so that when you `creating a new row` you can also get the Iformfile for the image.

Then pls follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61313891) to upload your image to azure storage blob. Here's the code snippet when I test in my side:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> uploadFile(TestModel mod)
        {
            var connectionstring = "connection_string";
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionstring);
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container_name");
            await blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            BlobClient blobClent = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(mod.fileName);
            BlobHttpHeaders httpheaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
            {
                ContentType = mod.img.ContentType
            };
            await blobClent.UploadAsync(mod.img.OpenReadStream(), httpheaders);
            return "success";
        }
```

[image]
[image]