# javascript: Not sending array with fetch api

Tags: javascript, c#, json, fetch, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to send array with fetch api. but it goes null.

javascript:

```
const url = "/TMF/DownloadFolderFilesAsZip";

        var data = {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                folderFiles: foldersFiles
            }),
            headers: new Headers({
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            })
        }

        fetch(url, data)
            .then(resp => resp.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.style.display = 'none';
                a.href = url;
                a.download = "document" + ".zip";
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            })
            .catch(() => alert(''));
```

data:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {fileId: '', folderId: 'e48634fb-23eb-45fa-b974-c83a3032db63'}
1: {fileId: '', folderId: 'c3bdd287-4461-4b5e-95c9-4048e8f34e58'}
length:2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task DownloadFolderFilesAsZip([FromBody] List<TmfZipFolderFiles> folderFiles)
        {
           ......
        }
```

c# class:

```
public class TmfZipFolderFiles
    {
        public Guid fileId { get; set; }
        public Guid folderId { get; set; }
        public Guid tenantId { get; set; }
        public Guid userId { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't send the array with the above codes. null data goes to the controller. How can I send the array?

Comment: First of all you should check in the developer tools of your browser what *really* is sent to the server. The sending ode per se looks fine (assuming that `foldersFiles` has the correct value). If your requests contains the expected body, the error might also be on the backend. But I can't help you with that, because I never worked with c# controllers

Answer (score 0):

The model you've inserted into the body is an object containing an array `{"folderFiles":[...]}`. Your backend is waiting for the array directly. e.g.: `[{...},{...}]` You should try editing the `body` of `data`.

```
JSON.stringify(foldersFiles)
```

Comment: I did what you said. but again it didn't.

Comment: Is your Controller configured to support JsonSerialize? Are you working on an API project or an MVC project? If MVC, what does the Controller inherit from?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue in my side and after I changed `public Guid fileId`
to `public string fileId`, and using `JSON.stringify(foldersFiles)`, it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: yes. thank you. such data is coming. but I need to send it as guid not string. how can I do?

Comment: just like you know, javascript only have `var` and don't have a date type GUID, so if you send a GUID in the fetch request, it would send as a string. so I'm afraid you need to convert string to Guid in your asp.net core web api, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104850/test-if-string-is-a-guid-without-throwing-exceptions) about the converting.

Comment: okay. thank you. did you use azure? to keep files as blobs

Comment: sounds like another question, I tried to follow micrsoft document to store images in azure storage blob.

Comment: Yes, this is a different issue. I'm saving a file to Azure. but I can't pull it as bytes. I found it somewhere. but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi, since it's a different question, you'd better to create a new question with related tags so that corresponding experts can see it and share their ideas. All I know about it is [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543042/14574199)