# Set ContentType on Azure BlobClient without wiping properties like ContentHash

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

You can set ContentType on Upload, and if you mess up you can set it afterwards [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945376/how-upload-blob-in-azure-blob-storage-with-specified-contenttype-with-net-v12-s)

So say I want to update ContentType:

```
public async Task FixContentTypeAsync(BlobClient file, string mimetype)
{
    await file.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders
    {
        ContentType = mimetype
    });
 }
```

**Problem** If I go get the file again, turns out I've wiped the ContentHash

**Work around** re-set all the other BlobHttpHeaders available:

```
public async Task FixContentTypeAsync(BlobClient file, string mimetype)
{
    var props = await file.GetPropertiesAsync();
    var before = props.Value;
    await file.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders
    {
        ContentType = mimetype,
        CacheControl = before.CacheControl,
        ContentDisposition = before.ContentDisposition,
        ContentEncoding = before.ContentEncoding,
        ContentHash = before.ContentHash,
        ContentLanguage = before.ContentLanguage,
    });
}
```

I essentially want to do a JsonPatch and just edit this attribute on it's own without worrying about possibly wiping a property I don't know about, slightly worried that the SetHttpHeadersAsync implementation will change in the future and I'll end up wiping some other metatdata that wasn't there in the previous version.

Is there any "safer" way to do this? It's fine if there isn't, it's scary it lets me programmatically wipe a bunch of metadata that I didn't mean to touch.

Edit: I checked setting ContentEncoding on upload, and it doesn't get wiped if I use code snippet 1

Comment: It seems that it is a limit. We need to provide these headers together. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties#remarks

Comment: I've lost metadata doing something similar with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage so was more cautious when updating to Azure.Storage. I wanted a PATCH for idiot-proofing&future-proofing but it's implemented like a whole object PUT, I'll accept that as a dev, sometimes I'm the user that needs training and maybe there's a reason it was written that way. My goal is to not lose data while trying to fix it and I can do that, pfftt how many other people have accidently wiped ContentHashes by not reading the docs, I don't mind being the only idiot. (Also I'd have accepted this as an answer)